# Invariant Violation:Element type is invalid:expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for components)

Tags: react-native

these code is a reference of fetch user list but when i am running in my react native app its stuck and i made some es5 codes changes but still its not working and the error is same...

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import { List, ListItem, SearchBar } from "react-native-elements";

class Follow extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      data: [],
      page: 1,
      seed: 1,
      error: null,
      refreshing: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.makeRemoteRequest();
  }

  makeRemoteRequest (){
    const { page, seed } = this.state;
    const url = `https://randomuser.me/api/?seed=${seed}&page=${page}&results=20`;
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          data: page === 1 ? res.results : [...this.state.data, ...res.results],
          error: res.error || null,
          loading: false,
          refreshing: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error, loading: false });
      });
  };

  handleRefresh () {
    this.setState(
      {
        page: 1,
        seed: this.state.seed + 1,
        refreshing: true
      },
      () => {
        this.makeRemoteRequest();
      }
    );
  };

  handleLoadMore(){
    this.setState(
      {
        page: this.state.page + 1
      },
      () => {
        this.makeRemoteRequest();
      }
    );
  };

  renderSeparator  () {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          width: "86%",
          backgroundColor: "#CED0CE",
          marginLeft: "14%"
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  renderHeader () {
    return <SearchBar placeholder="Type Here..." lightTheme round />;
  };

  renderFooter(){
    if (!this.state.loading) return null;

    return (
      <View
        style={{
          paddingVertical: 20,
          borderTopWidth: 1,
          borderColor: "#CED0CE"
        }}
      >
        <ActivityIndicator animating size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <List containerStyle={{ borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem
              roundAvatar
              title={`${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`}
              subtitle={item.email}
              avatar={{ uri: item.picture.thumbnail }}
              containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.email}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
          ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
          onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
          onEndReachedThreshold={50}
        />
      </List>
    );
  }
}

export default Follow;
```

tried many times new method but still 
**the error is same** 
* I can't find where is the issue let me knw...*
the error is defined in render method it shows ...

Comment: When you said `es5 code changes`, do you mean you changed the code *from* ES5, or *to* ES5?

Comment: From ES5 to arrow funcion